# view the column names for CSV file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

i have a CSV file i want to get the columns name for each column

sample :

[image]

how can i do that with awk or sed or grep ??

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
head -n 1 file.csv
```

or

```
sed 1q file.csv
```

or

```
grep -m 1 '' file.csv
```

or

```
awk 'NR==1 {print; exit}' file.csv
```

Comment: As `print` is the default action you can shorten the `awk` command to `awk NR==1 file.csv`.

Comment: @dessert: Thank you. I'm aware [of that](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/e961d1fb-44e6-4a71-806e-2146800f251c/view-source). This way awk reads only the first line of the file.

Comment: I don’t understand – `awk 'NR==1 {print; exit}'` does the exact same as `awk NR==1`.

Comment: @dessert when `awk NR==1`, still awk will read your whole file's lines where those are not necessary to read. Also that can be only `awk '{print; exit}'`

Comment: or `awk '1;{exit}'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `csvtool` to obtain column names. First install it from Ubuntu repository:

```
apt install csvtool
```

Then run it on the csv file:

```
csvtool head 1 file.csv
```

Output:

```
name1,name2,name3
```

If You need each column name in a separate line use `tr` command like this:

```
csvtool head 1 file.csv | tr -s ',' '\n'

name1
name2
name3
```

Answer (score 2):

While the answer for `awk` or `sed` or `grep` above is amazing, I would like to offer an alternative solution for those people who are not familiar with queries. You can use a Relational Database Management System (RDBMS) or some other tools, such as [Acho](https://acho.io/), to process your CSVs.

#### How to upload a CSV and view the column name

1. **Upload your CSV using *Add Resource***

   You can choose CSV or MCSV to upload, just make sure that all the CSVs have the same data schema (same column name, column number, column data type) if you are using MCSV.
2. **CSV Preview**

   After the file selection, you can use the CSV Preview mode to see all your column names and columns. Additionally, you can choose to turn on the *Auto-detect Schema* or the *Safe Mode*. *Auto-detect Schema* can automatically detect the CSV's column name and column types for you. If the 1st upload fails, try to upload it with the *Safe Mode on, which turns all the column data types into "string" for the CSV.

   If your CSV doesn't consist of any column name in the header row, just click *Add a header row* and edit those column names then. This way, your CSV will have the 1st row as its column name, which is super beneficial for your later data work.
3. **Add the CSV into a project and have the whole table**

   After the CSV has been successfully uploaded, just add this CSV resource into a project for the data manipulation. Then open it in the project. You can easily see your CSV presented in a table with all its column names.

   [image: CSV with all its column names]